# My SilverStripe module overrides other modules display

Tags: php, templates, silverstripe

I'm writing a subscribe module to plugin to the [SilverStripe Blog](http://addons.silverstripe.org/add-ons/silverstripe/blog) module. So far I have my yml as:

```
---
Name: subscription
After: 'framework/*','cms/*'
---
Blog:
  extensions:
    - Subscription
Page_Controller:
  extensions:
    - SubscriptionWidget
```

And my SubscriptionWidget.php:

```
<?php
class SubscriptionWidget extends DataExtension {

    public function SubscriptionWidget() {
        $controller = SubscriptionWidget_Controller::create();
        $form = $controller->SubscriptionWidget();
        return $form;
    }
}

class SubscriptionWidget_Controller extends Controller {
    private static $allowed_actions = array('SubscriptionWidget');

    public function SubscriptionWidget () {
        $form = Form::create(
            $this,
            __FUNCTION__,
            FieldList::create(
                TextField::create('Email', 'Email'),
                TextField::create('Name', 'Name')
            ),
            FieldList::create(
                FormAction::create('submit', 'Subscribe')
            )
        );//->setTemplate('SubscriptionWidget');
        return $form;
    }

    public function submit($data, $form) {
        return $this->redirect('/subscribed');
    }

}
```

At the moment this works as intended however another plugin I use called [BetterNavigator](https://github.com/jonom/silverstripe-betternavigator) disappears from the screen. If I take out

```
Page_Controller:
  extensions:
  - SubscriptionWidget
```

from my yml it reappears. I've looked through both code bases which are quite simple and there are no conflicting functions. I've also tried using `ContentController` instead of `Page_Controller` and my template disappears until I disable BetterNavigator and then it reappears. I do have one or two pretty empty classes but all are called some variation of Subscriber while there is only one function in BetterNavigator called BetterNavigator.

Why would this be happening?

Comment: Have you tried changing the "Before" or "After"part of your YMAL so that it 
it references the other module to ensure it is before or after it?

Comment: @Barry just tried `Before: 'betternavigator/*'` and after and no difference.

Comment: What versions of SS and BetterNavigator module do you use?

Comment: @GregSmirnov seem to be running 2.1 and 3 is out :/ Would having an old version seriously cause this oddity?

Comment: Did you place `$BetterNavigator` somewhere in your template(s) to use BetterNavigator?

Comment: Yeah, only difference between the two is the YML to turn on / off the class override.

Answer (score 1):

I see only one clash in your code that results in incorrect runtime behaviour. Your method `SubscriptionWidget::SubscriptionWidget()` is treated as legacy class constructor. So I suggest you thinking about better class and method names.

```
class SubscriptionWidget extends Extension
{
    // explicitly defined constructor
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    // now this one is normal function
    public function SubscriptionWidget() {
        $controller = SubscriptionWidget_Controller::create();
        $form = $controller->SubscriptionWidget();
        return $form;
    }
}
```